# Как обеспечить последовательную печать с fork

Tags: c++, файлы, unix, процесс

Проблема заключается в следующем: пишу программу, написал функцию для принта в логи, решил ее оптимизировать, сделав там вызов fork() (пишу под Linux) и отдав всю печать дочернему процессу, пока родительский возвращается из функции и продолжает работу основной программы. Но я заметил, что если в главной программе часто (скорее быстро) вызывать эту функцию, то последовательность печати нарушается. Я использую мьютексы, но это не особо помогает. Буду рад любой помощи.

Код:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

#define LOGS "logs.txt"

void logprint(const char *str, ...)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid>0) // father
        signal(SIGCLD,SIG_IGN);

    if(pid==0) // child
    {
        std::mutex locker;
        locker.lock();

        va_list args;
        va_start(args, str);

        std::ofstream logs(LOGS, std::ios_base::app); // writing to the end of file

        logs.flush();

        auto t = std::time(nullptr);
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
        logs << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") << " :: ";

        char *p = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        memcpy(p, str, strlen(str)+1);
        for(; *p; p++)
        {
            if(*p != '%')
            {
                logs << *p;
                continue;
            }
            switch(*++p)
            {
            case 'e':
                logs << "ERROR::";
                break;
            case 'd':
            {
                unsigned long int ival = va_arg(args, unsigned long int);
                logs << ival;
                break;
            }
            case 'f':
            {
                double dval = va_arg(args, double);
                logs << dval;
                break;
            }
            case 's':
            {
                char *sval = va_arg(args, char*);
                logs << sval;
                break;
            }
            default:
                logs << *p;
                break;
            }
        }
        logs << "\n";

        va_end(args);
        logs.flush();
        logs.close();
        locker.unlock();
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        logprint("%d", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 4
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 2
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 0
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 5
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 6
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 7
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 3
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 1
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 8
17-07-2018 15:14:22 :: 9
```

Comment: Насколько важно писать немедленно? Может, выделить буфер в памяти и писать в него, а уж его сбрасывать асинхронно и пореже - по заполнению этого буфера?

Comment: Это самая настоящая анти-оптимизация. Форкать новый процесс на каждый возов функции - просто жесть. `std::mutex` работает в рамках одного процесса, а для нескольких процессов придется задействовать механизмы IPC.

Comment: @VTT, ну, зато основная программа идет дальше, не зависая на печати. Разве форк занимает больше времени, чем печать? Всегда только и слышал, что самая медленная операция - это печать. Про IPC почитаю, спасибо

Comment: @Harry, ну, что-то мне такой вариант не очень нравится, получается, что если программа дошла до определенного места и отчиталась об этом, но буфер не заполнился, но это не будет напечатано, пока не дойдет очередь до следующего сообщения? А если она упадет на этом промежутке? А пишу я сервер, так что инфа нужна во время

Comment: Для параллельности в рамках одного процесса есть [потоки выполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (execution threads). Там вам как раз пригодятся мьютексы. Преимущество (да и недостаток) в том, что там будет общее адресное пространство и обмениваться данными будет возможно без всяких IPC. Создание процесса - это более ресурсоёмкая операция, чем создание потока.

Comment: Создайте поток, заведите очередь строк (только защитите её мютексом на вытаскивание/добавление одной строки). В потоке раз в некоторый интервал времени вытаскивайте строки из очереди и печатайте. Только не вытаскивайте все строки из очереди, поставьте ограничение, например, не больше 200 строк за раз. А в функциях logprint просто формируйте очередную строку и кладите её в очередь для печати.

Comment: [syslog](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Syslog-Example.html) вообще-то [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20667953/4827341)